# connecting to remote sql server express 2008. is this normal?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-connection

Every tutorial I see on the internet on how to connect to remote sql server using management studio will say I enter ip-adress\sqlexpress for the server name. When I do that i get  the most famous nework-related/instance-specific error, but when I enter only the ip-adress everything goes smoothly. is this normal? is this fine?

Comment: You have an issue with a successful connection?

Comment: How have you installed the SQL Server? Is it a named instance or a default instance?

Comment: yeah i have an issue when i user `server_ip\sqlexpress`. i get the following error:

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)`.



but when i just use `server_ip`, i'm able to connect successfully.

Comment: i've installed sql server 2008 and management studio. I've enabled TCP/IP. I'm not sure what named instance is as i'm just a newbie in sql server.

Comment: Did you give a name for the server?

Comment: Then it is a named instance, and as the only SQL Server on the machine, it is also the default instance (which is why just an IP works). Since you _gave_ it a name, it is not called `sqlexpress` anymore - which is why you get errors using that name.

Comment: huh, wait. Let me get this right. it's like i'm a bit confused now. by server name you mean where my database is sitting? because i can use the ip adress or my domain name as the server name when i log in. and i've created my database called `mytestdb` and a database user `mytestuser`. So i'm using `mytestuser`'s credentials to log in.

Comment: You can install several _different_ instances of SQL Server on a specific machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing SQL Server, you gave the instance a name (as you have mentions in [your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230389/connecting-to-remote-sql-server-express-2008-is-this-normal#comment16389374_12230389) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230389/connecting-to-remote-sql-server-express-2008-is-this-normal#comment16389581_12230389)).

Since it is a named instance, and probably the only SQL Server on the machine, it is also the default instance (which is why just an IP works).

Since you gave the instance a name, it is not called `sqlexpress` (unless you chose that name, and from the error, I am assuming you did not) - which is why you get errors using that name.